# writing tests for react-native integrating RTK Query with Components

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, rtk-query

I am using RTK Query Hooks in my expo react native project.Now I am willing to write test for the component contains RTK Query Hook?.

Can Someone else share me the steps how to writing test for integrating RTK Query in react native components.

I tried in google not able to find any reference.

In redux asking to use msw but it is not supporting for react native app.
https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#integration-testing-connected-components-and-redux-logic

I tried with msw/node but it throws an errow not supported